# How to test sending form data through Javascript locally?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning about sending forms through JavaScript by manually building XMLHttpRequest.
In the end of given example, there's a note:

> Note: This use of XMLHttpRequest is subject to the same-origin policy if you want to send data to a third party web site. For cross-origin requests, you'll need CORS and HTTP access control.

I'd like to test the example locally, though. What can I change to make it work locally? The address of posting request?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button>Click me!</button>

    <script>
        function sendData(data) {
            console.log('Sending data');

            const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let urlEncodedData = "",
                urlEncodedDataPairs = [],
                name;

            for (name in data) {
                urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[name]));
            }

            urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace('/%20/g', '+');

            XHR.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
            });

            XHR.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
                alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
            });

            XHR.open('POST', 'https://example.com/cors.php');
            XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            XHR.send(urlEncodedData);
        }

        const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            sendData({ test: 'ok' });
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "What can I change to make it work locally? The address of posting request?" — Yes … which you have to do because the example one won't work!

Comment: which address should i use then?

Comment: The address of the server-side code you write to handle your data.

Comment: this is just example on which i'm learning so i have no such real code

Comment: The example assumes you have working forms with a backend already.

Comment: @bb8 You can happily play around using `XMLHttpRequest` without having a backend sever running locally. I assume you are learning web development and are not very comforable with this stuff. You can just change the URL to a free, publicly available API and your network requests will work -- to a certain extent, of course.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a fake REST API service, like https://reqres.in. Basic usage is free and requires no registration whatsoever.

They usually send back fake data and don't require CORS.

You just need to change the URL to `https://reqres.in/api/users` for example.

Comment: yes, i'm just learning, and still haven't got to server-side part. i used this url and it displayed their provided information. if i want my message (alert) to work, what do i need to do?

Comment: If your click handler runs, the alert should be displayed correctly. I tested your sendData function directly and it works for me, alert is displayed.

Comment: did you get the `'load'` handler working? i couldn't

Comment: It works, without modifications, an my machine, under Chrome 83. Maybe you accidentally changed something. Is there error output in the console? Did you save the file and refresh the browser?

Comment: i get '{"id":"557","createdAt":"2020-07-20T18:50:12.618Z"}' in the alert message, but i expect to get my provided message

Comment: Free, public fake APIs usually send their own responses, regardless of what you send, so that's that.